# How to create a matrix in Dart?

Tags: collections, flutter, dart

I have a `List<String>` and I want to create a square matrix (2-dimensional array/list) of `Set<String>` with the same dimensions as the length of the `List<String>`.

I tried using

```
List.filled(entries.length, List.filled(entries.length, Set<String>()));
```

but the problem is that it seems that each row of my matrix refers to the same list instance, so changing a value in one row changes it in all the others as well.

So then I tried

```
List.filled(entries.length, List.from(List.filled(entries.length, Set<String>())));
```

but I still have the same problem. Eventually I surrendered and resorted to

```
List<List<Set<String>>> matrix = [];

for(int i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    List<Set<String>> row = [];
    for (int n = 0; n<entries.length; n++) {
        row.add(Set<String>());
    }
    matrix.add(row);
}
```

It works, but it's ugly. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List.generate(n, (_) => List.generate(n, (_) => <String>{}));
```

Comment: With the new list literal syntax, you can even do: `List<List<Set<String>>> matrix = [for (var _ in entries) [ for (var _ in entries) {} ]];` or `... = [for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) [ for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {}]];`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you could use [Matrix2](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix2-class.html) class (or matrixes with other dimensions: Matrix3, Matrix4). Unfortunately, I have no experience in using these classes, but maybe it has a sense for you. These classes have constructors for generating matrix from lists.